# Call a function of array with certain defintion

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

I am using a couple of arrays defined by e.g.

```
  public arr1() as variant
```

and they strictly need the ()-part after the variable name to work in the preexisting code.

however if I try to rearrange them by 1) joining text by a delimiter ":-:" (filltering out unwanted data in a for-loop),
the split function don't work:

arr1=Split(tmpString, ":-:")

And again I am strictly restrained to using the variants as defined above.

I am very greatfull for any help!

Comment: `Split` returns an array of `String`s, so you need to convert the result to an array of `Variant`s, as demonstrated in the linked thread.

Comment: Thanks, I just found another solution here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515352/how-to-convert-string-type-array-to-variant-type-array-excel-vba

Comment: That's another option, but note it's limited to Excel. The linked solution is host-agnostic.

Comment: There the solution is to insert the string-array into cells in worksheet and then back again from there to a predefined array() in the variant-form. Worked perfectly :)

Comment: You don't need to write to the worksheet at all. Example: `Dim arr() As Variant`
    `arr = WorksheetFunction.Index(Split("foo;bar", ";"), 1, 0)`.

Comment: Ah, well, yes and no-, It is now an array in the string format, as seen in the "locals"-window where the array-elements are defined as "Variant/String". So if the variables need specifically to be "Variant/Variant", then it doesn't work, unfortunately.... :(

Comment: That detail was not specified in your question, but you can easily modify the first approach (loop) to cast each `String` to a `Variant`.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I found out now that it was indeed variant/string. My bad. I were confusing two variables with each other. Thank you for the help. Then i don't need the intermediate steep anymore either :) Have a good weekend